# Agregar estilo a una tabla desde javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, estilos

Amigos

Soy novato en el JavaScript, por favor podrían guiarme sobre cómo en este código que genera una tabla, agregar también estilos como un borde y un color. El código funciona y me genera una tabla con 3 campos, muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos

mostrarEmpleados=function(){

```
let cmpTabla = document.getElementById("tablaEmpleados");
let contenidoTabla = "<table><tr>" +
    "<th>CEDULA</th>" +
    "<th>NOMBRE</th>" +
    "<th>APELLIDO</th>" +
    "<th>SUELDO</th>" +
    "</tr>";

let elementoEmpleados;
for (let i = 0; i < empleados.length; i++) {
    elementoEmpleados = empleados[i];
    contenidoTabla +=
        "<tr><td>" + elementoEmpleados.cedula + "</td>"
        + "<td>" + elementoEmpleados.nombre + "</td>"
        + "<td>" + elementoEmpleados.apellido + "</td>"
        + "<td>" + elementoEmpleados.sueldo + "</td>"
        + "</tr>"
}
contenidoTabla += "</table>";
cmpTabla.innerHTML = contenidoTabla;
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué has intentado para agregar los estilos? ¿Qué errores te salen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si lo que deseas es agregar estilos a cmpTabla podrías hacer algo como esto

```
cmpTabla.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
cmpTabla.style.borderColor = 'red';
cmpTabla.style.fontSize = '2rem';
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rápida respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la linea que crea la tabla por esta otra para añadir un id a la tabla:

```
let contenidoTabla = "<table id=\"tabla_empleados\"><tr>" +
```

Luego añade el css que necesites en el fichero HTML, cuando salga la tabla tendrá los estilos.

```
#tabla_empleados{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#tabla_empleados th{
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#tabla_empleados td{
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

#tabla_empleados tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```js
let cmpTabla = document.getElementById("tablaEmpleados");
let contenidoTabla = `<table id="tabla_empleados"><tr>
    <th>CEDULA</th>
    <th>NOMBRE</th>
    <th>APELLIDO</th>
    <th>SUELDO</th>
    </tr>`

let elementoEmpleados;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    contenidoTabla +=
        `<tr>
        <td> cedula ${i + 1}</td>
        <td>nombre ${i + 1}</td>
        <td>apellido ${i + 1}</td>
        <td>sueldo ${i + 1}</td>
        </tr>`
}
contenidoTabla += `</table>`;
cmpTabla.innerHTML = contenidoTabla;
```

```css
#tabla_empleados{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#tabla_empleados th{
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#tabla_empleados td{
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

#tabla_empleados tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tablaEmpleados"></div>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo con tu código para que lo veas, recuerda que he cambiado el For para que saque datos de prueba

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo